# XAMPP Mod_Rewrite & dynamic CSS

Tags: mod-rewrite, xampp, dynamic-css

I'm running Apache on my local computer (mac) with Mod_Rewite enabled and Allowoveride All set in XAMPP's httpd.conf file.

These are my rules, snippet of httpd.conf file -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/setup/css/userlayout.css /setup/css/userlayout.php

Alias /ms "/Users/web/wwwroot/ms"

<Directory "/Users/web/wwwroot/ms">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

In my index.php file I have -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="setup/css/userlayout.css?u=1" />
```

And in my userlayout.php file is -

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/css');
    echo "#test{background-color:#000;}";
?>
```

Thats everything but the rules don't do anything. I'm not sure if I'm putting the rules in the right place and I understand that you can do this in a httpd.conf file and not the .htaccess file.

Comment: Try the rules in your `<VirtualHost>` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. XAMPP setup requires the line "Options +FollowSymLinks" for mod_rewrite to work. Also this has to be placed within the directory tag not outside of it as rewrite rules work per directory which is why i was receiving the error on "RewriteBase /" directive.

Thus the full code is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks 
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /root
    RewriteRule ^setup/css/userlayout\.css$ setup/css/userlayout\.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

RewriteRule ^/setup/css/userlayout.css$ /setup/css/userlayout.php

You can see more about RewriteRule [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

Comment: Nope nothing. I suspect there is nothing wrong with the rule. Infact I can't prove if mod-rewrite is working at all except if put in RewriteBase / I get a big error message which I shouldn't be getting at all. hmmm....

Comment: If you are using the latest version of XAMPP (for windows) I'm quite sure it is installed and active by default.

Comment: must be something else then. anybody got any ideas?